# Unsupported URL protocol

Tags: git, go

I'm trying to create a basic GO app to pull a Git repo using git2go but I'm getting an error saying unsupported URL protocol. Does anyone know why?

```
package main

import (
    git "github.com/libgit2/git2go"
    "log"

)

func main() {

    cloneOptions := &git.CloneOptions{}

    repo, err := git.Clone("https://github.com/nova-framework/framework.git", "gittest", cloneOptions)
            if err != nil {
                    log.Panic(err)
            }
    log.Print(repo)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your libgit2 was probably not compiled with the required flags for HTTPS: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/b7809b84692b4df7f11d603cc5da0860609e0555/src/transport.c#L32-L34

The pre-processor is looking for one of these to be defined:

```
GIT_OPENSSL, GIT_WINHTTP, GIT_SECURE_TRANSPORT
```

From the [README](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2#compiler-and-linker-options), it looks like you need these three, which probably cause the requirements to be met:

> ZLIB_LIBRARY, OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY AND OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY: Tell
>   CMake where to find those specific libraries